# Node.js Mongoose and using find with request.params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections stored in a MongoDB: Markers and Pois

MarkerID is a foreign key in Pois and primary key in Markers.

I want to return Pois with a certain Marker ID

I can do this in MongoDB console:

```
>db.PoiPois.find({"MarkerID":78})
```

I can also do this  with a hardcoded query in a Node.js app using express RESTful routes and Mongoose:

```
app.get('/pois/:markerid', function(req, res) {
 poiModel.find({MarkerID:78}, function (err,pois) {
        res.contentType('json');
    res.json({
        success: true,
      data: pois

    });
 });
});
```

I want to replace the  hardcoded query with a dynamic one, using the request parameter for markerid so do the following:

```
poiModel.find({MarkerID:req.params.markerid}, function (err,pois) {
```

but this does not work (returns empty json).

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `req.params.markerid` is a string. Try converting it to integer.

Comment: Yup. And the easiest way to do that would be `{MarkerID: +req.params.markerid}`

Comment: @danmactough: wow, nice trick! Is it reliable? Any gotchas (as compared to `parseInt`)? :)

Comment: Sergio, I think I'd be comfortable using it where I know what kind of string I expect to be giving it. In a sense, it's more "reliable" than `parseInt` because strings with leading zeroes still get cast using base 10. Also, it will cast strings with decimals, like `parseFloat`. Truthfully, though, in a db query I'd be performing some validation before I got to the query parameter.

Comment: All helpful comments. Thank you. The code that worked for me was  app.get('/pois/:markerid', function(req, res) {
 poiModel.find({MarkerID: +req.params.markerid}, function (err,pois) {
  res.contentType('json');
  res.json({
      success: true,
    data: pois

  });
 });
}); In my ignorance I was calling with an unnecessary  colon in my url: //http://localhost:5000/pois/:1234. This obviously made the value of req.params.markerid = ":1234"